# Wordpress Loop to display Category and posts under

Tags: wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I'm new to worpdress. I've only just gotten this query to work with a custom post type I made but now I've run into another issue when it came to following the design specifications of the website.

This page is supposed to display the products under their respective Categories. The loop I have made only shows each product but does not display the category of it for all of them.

I was intending for it to look something like this:

CAT

- ITEM
- ITEM
- ITEM
- ITEM

CAT

- ITEM
- ITEM
- ITEM
- ITEM

But instead I'm only getting this:

- ITEM
- ITEM
- ITEM

I'm not looking for something like this:

- ITEM, cat under title
- ITEM, cat under title
- ITEM, cat under title

  ```
    <?php
  $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
  );

  $loop = new WP_query( $args );

  if($loop->have_posts()):
    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="post-loop-single">
        <div class="thumbnail-img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?> </span></a></div>
        <div class="post-loop-text">
          <div class="post-loop-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;
  endif;
  ```

  ?>

Answer (score 0):

First get all product categories using `get_terms()` then get product related to this categories using `tax_query` in argument. Please check below code it help you.

```
$args = array(  
        'orderby'   => 'title',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
    );  
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );  
$count = count($product_categories);  
if ( $count > 0 ){  
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {

        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';  
            $args =array('posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'orderby' => 'title',                                
                        'tax_query' => array('relation' => 'AND',  
                                            array(  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => $product_category->slug  
                                                )  
                                            ),  
                        );  
            $products = new WP_Query( $args );  

            while ( $products->have_posts() ) { $products->the_post();  ?>  

                <div class="post-loop-single">
                    <div class="thumbnail-img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?> </span></a></div>
                    <div class="post-loop-text">
                        <div class="post-loop-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
     <?php  }  wp_reset_query();

    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. the code somehow didn't work for me. it says it got a "catchable error" on the line of the echo. some further digging into the other questions similar to mine do use a foreach loop but I currently don't understand how to use it yet with this particular case.

Comment: Please provide more information about error and what code you try. share screenshot if possible